# Perl Encode::Guess doesn't know about simple ISO-8859-1/latin1 characters?

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am trying to figure out the encoding of many inputted strings, some in UTF-8, some in ISO-8859-1.  Unfortunate.

I am using Perl with [`Encode::Guess`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::Guess), and I'm surprised to see it can't handle a simple Latin1 encoding. I'm using the decode example from the Encode::Guess documentation.

I've been reading in a file, but I can also hard code the string to get the same error:

```
use Encode::Guess;

my $data = "The name \xc5sa is Swedish\n";
my $enc = guess_encoding($data,qw/latin1 utf8 ascii/);
ref($enc) or die "Can't guess: $enc\nFOR: $data";
```

And I get:

```
Can't guess: No appropriate encodings found!
FOR: The name �sa is Swedish
```

Though in my editor, I am seeing "Åsa" with the Aring as the first character.

Is Perl predetermining the encoding because it's a string as opposed to a packed set of binary data, and that's what is breaking this?

I tried `use open ":encoding(Latin1)";` when I was reading from a file, and the error went away, but it guessed the encoding to be UTF-8. Regardless, the file mixes UTF-8 and Latin1 on a line-by-line basis, so I want to run `Encode::Guess` for each line.

I also tried `binmode` on the file handle, and still saw the error.

Comment: If the file contains a mixture of Latin-1 and UTF8 (and perhaps even some CP1252) then I'd recommend you try [Encoding::FixLatin](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encoding::FixLatin).

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings 'all';`!!! If you had, your code would have produced the telltale `Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at a.pl line 3.`

Comment: @GrantMcLean: Perhaps you should say that it's your own module?

Comment: For shame (misssing the 'qw') - I've updated the question.

Comment: @DavidLjungMadison: What remains unanswered by my solution below?

Comment: @Borodin, mostly just me being asleep.  :)

I've also edited the question to fix the typo - I never saw the warning because I didn't have warnings on - regardless, the top of your answer refers to the pre-edited question.  :)

Comment: Was the typo in your actual code, or just in the question? If it was in your actual code, you shouldn't edit the question to get rid of the typo, since that invalidates Jim Garrison's answer and part of Borodin's. It also makes things confusing for future visitors; right now both answers refer to a typo that's not in the question.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I hear what you are saying, but I've pointed out to them that the answer could be edited.  Normally I would keep the error in if that was what the question was about, but it wasn't, and I think the lesson about unicode encoding is *far* more important than a silly typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is faulty. The parameter `/latin1 utf8 ascii/` is attempting to apply a regex pattern to the (undefined) variable `$_`. You will have seen a warning message

> Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//)

which you really should have told us about

Note that `use open ":encoding(Latin1)"` is the same as applying `binmode $fh, ":encoding(Latin1)"` to every file handle as you open it, and will attempt to decode the data as Latin1 as you read it. The result will be a string that uses Perl's internal encoding for what were Latin1 characters in the file. If some of it is UTF-8 then that would be disastrous. The UTF-8 encoding for the A-ring character is the two bytes `C3` `85` which, treated as Latin1, is A-tilde followed by an illegal character

This should work for you

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Encode::Guess;

for my $data (
        "The name \xC5sa is Swedish\n",
        "The name \N{U+00C5}sa is Swedish\n" ) {

    my $enc = guess_encoding($data, qw/ latin1 utf8 ascii /);
    ref($enc) or die "Can't guess: $enc\nFOR: $data";

    say $enc->name;
}
```

#### output

```
iso-8859-1
utf8
```

---

#### Update

I highly recommend Grant McLean's [`Encoding::FixLatin`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encoding::FixLatin) module, which does everything that you need. It will also cover the case where both encodings are used in a single line

This program processes a string encoded using `Latin1` and another using `UTF-8`. Both are printed without any problem after processing them using `fix_latin`

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use open qw/ :std :encoding(UTF-8) /;

use Encoding::FixLatin 'fix_latin';

for my $data (
        "The name \xC5sa is Swedish\n",
        "And so is Asbj\N{U+00F6}rn\n" ) {

    my $utf8 = fix_latin($data);
    print $utf8;
}
```

#### output

```
The name Åsa is Swedish
And so is Asbjörn
```

It is probably best to read and process the entire file in one pass using this technique. There is no point in reading the file line-by-line unless it is enormous and would cause memory problems

Comment: FixLatin makes a lot of sense, though I'd rather not install new libraries to solve this.

The guess_encoding doesn't completely work when I read a file line-by-line with `binmode :utf8`.  On my system, perl Encode can't guess if a utf-8 encoding of é (0xc3 0xa9) is actually utf-8 or latin1 for Ã©.  I guess that's one of the problems with guessing encoding, and probably where fix_latin is really helpful.  guess_encoding returns both utf-8 and latin1, and right now I think I can just go with guessing utf-8 in those cases and hope for the best.

Answer (score 4):

This line

```
my $enc = guess_encoding($data,/latin1 utf8 ascii/);
```

should be

```
my $enc = guess_encoding($data,qw/latin1 utf8 ascii/);
                               ^^
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that embarassing typo - I've updated the question.